# How do you check whether a button is enabled or not in Android?

Tags: android, button, isenabled

In Android I can set a button to be enabled or disabled by doing the following:

`button.setEnabled(true);` or `button.setEnabled(false);`

How do I check whether the button enabled state is true or false?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Reading the manual every now and then doesn't hurt:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isEnabled%28%29

Example:

```
ImageButton myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.epic_button);

if (myButton.isEnabled()){
    //then the button is enabled.
}
```

Comment: it doesn't hurt for sure.  I was looking for getEnable() and didn't think about isEnable()

Comment: :) As a general rule, for toggling properties out there, you'll have a "setProperty" to set it, and a "isProperty" to check what's its value ^_^

Comment: How can one be notified when that value changes?  For instance, I need to let the children of a ViewGroup of the parents' isEnabled state.

Answer (score 10):

```
button.isEnabled()
```

returns true if enabled